# Vlookup on strings

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am trying to put a dropdown on one cell in the sheet and based on the drop down selection need to have a lookup on the adjacent cell with range of values specified in another sheet.

Spent considerate time on this and couldn't figure out since I am a tableau developer and VBA is not my strong suit.Can someone help me on this one. Thanks!

```
Worksheets("DailySales").Range("B3") = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup( _
    Worksheets("DailySales").Range("A3"), Worksheets("Accounts").Range("A2:B40"), 2, False)
```

DailySales.A3 has the dropdown list of Account Names based on the selected value B3 needs to be populated with the AccountId's from `Accounts.Range("A2:B40")`

Comment: Assuming the dropdown list is a **Data Validation** list, you don't need VBA. Just use vlookup formula on B3 (may as well add **IFERROR**). Otherwise you need to account this on Worksheet_Change event for any changes on A3.

Comment: I wanted to use VBA code because the objective of this project is to enter data on DailySales and hit transfer button to move data to respective sheets based on AccountID. This will remove the formula on the cell. Need to create a VBA code formula to auto generate on the column upto 1000 rows not necessarily the single cell.

Comment: Could you show some sample data with expected output? It seems like you may be wanting to apply a formula to a range.

Comment: AccountName|AccountID|Date|VocherNumber|MS/HSD|Lts|Rate Amount
K Bhasker Rao|7|3/13/2018|234567|MS|35|67.71|2369.85  This is the Daily sales Worksheet

Comment: AccountName AccountID
Waterworks 1
Karthika Enterprises 2
Laxmi Enterprises 3
My Home Ready Mix 4
MSR PTC 5
Hyd Rock Sand 6
K Bhasker Rao 7    This is the accounts Worksheet.   Need to be able to do a lookup on the Dailysheets worksheet AccountID column based on drop down selection on the accountName.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Range("B3").FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(ISBLANK(RC[-1]),"""",VLOOKUP(RC[-1],Accounts!R2C1:R40C2,2,))"
Range("B3").Copy
Range("B3:B1000").PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
```

This is the working code. If someone else is also looking for.